# Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\Api\Products.php on line 21

Tags: magento

> Notice: Undefined index: state in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\Api\Products.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI - assumed 'OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\Api\Products.php on line 20

**Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\Api\Products.php on line 21**

Comment: Provide the code sample which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **oauth**

Command is here 
`pecl install oauth`